# Connection Node app with MongoDB hosted in a Droplet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection, digital-ocean

I am now trying to host my Angular, Node, MongoDB app on DigitalOcean. I have succesfully set up the two Droplets, one for Node Backend and one for MongoDB Database. Until now I was using a local link to connect to local database like the following link `mongodb://localhost:27017/creditApp` .

How do I connect my Node app hosted in Droplet to the MongoDB hosted in another Droplet? The database has admin password set up, also has allowed the IP address from my backend in the ufw list. I assume it needs a config object with admin name, password, ssh key .pub file etc and attach that object while trying to connect it, but I am not quite sure how to do it. How do I get this done?
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've searched a little on the DigitalOcean platform and I've learned, that every droplet is getting a datacenter local IPv4-Address. And it is possible to assign other IP-addresses (IPv4 and IPv6). Must be somewhere in the configuration of the droplet, where the IP-Addresses might show up.